# преобразование string type в hex type

Tags: python

требуется помощь, у меня есть строка вида `0x9daffbf...`

она ранее распознавалась как hex, то есть кавычки ей не требовались, суть моего скрипта в том, что генерируется часть hex строки после 0х, но на выходе получаю string. как преобразовать в hex, чтобы данная строка спокойно работал с методами для hex

```
z1 = '0x9daffbf33384ebbc40752b97d84cc423e81de251030cb7979e151e4377063e54'

print(int(z1, 16))
```

Answer (score 1):

Непонятна суть проблемы. Всё прекрасно работает и с `0x` впереди и без него:

```
z1 = '0x9daffbf33384ebbc40752b97d84cc423e81de251030cb7979e151e4377063e54'
z2 = int(z1, 16)
print(z2)
print(hex(z2))
print(hex(z2) == z1)
```

Вывод:

```
71324054358934732119009127994312035692819413935602478704025180570346368417364
0x9daffbf33384ebbc40752b97d84cc423e81de251030cb7979e151e4377063e54
True
```

Без `0x` впереди:

```
z1 = '9daffbf33384ebbc40752b97d84cc423e81de251030cb7979e151e4377063e54'
z2 = int(z1, 16)
print(z2)
print(hex(z2))
print(hex(z2) == '0x'+z1)
```

Вывод:

```
71324054358934732119009127994312035692819413935602478704025180570346368417364
0x9daffbf33384ebbc40752b97d84cc423e81de251030cb7979e151e4377063e54
True
```

И нет никакого "hex type", `hex()` просто делает строку с 16-ричным представлением числа и `0x` перед ней.

Comment: Я честно говоря так и не понял в чём была проблема, в использовании функции `hex`? )

Comment: проблема была в том, что не разобрался как преобразовать str с хексом в int, но благодаря вам проблема решена

Comment: Так у вас на скриншоте ровно этот же код, просто там печатается значение, а я его в переменную положил. Ну да ладно :)